# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './http-common' vue js axios

Tags: vue.js

I use this tutorial:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/
And tried to use axios like this:
in my main.js file:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://api.com/api/`,
    headers: {
        // Authorization: 'Bearer {token}'
    }
})
```

And in my .vue file:

```
import {HTTP} from './http-common';
let params = {
                    email: this.login,
                    pwd: this.pwd
                }
                HTTP.post(`login`, params)
                    .then(response => {
                        alert(response);
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
```

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/SignIn.vue
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './http-common' in
>   'C:\Users\direwolf\Documents\web\js\vue\quasar-crm\src\components'  @
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/SignIn.vue
>   5:0-37  @ ./src/components/SignIn.vue  @ ./src/router.js  @
>   ./src/main.js  @ multi ./build/hot-reload.js ./src/main.js

Answer (score 2):

**you need to import from main.js**

`import {HTTP} from './main';`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`import {HTTP} from './http-common';` to

`import {HTTP} from '../http-common';`

Hope this helps in some cases.